# cleaning dns cache does not work windows 7

Tags: caching, windows-7, dns

I have a domain `example.com`, I changed the name servers from cpanel, but opening it still opens the website with old DNS. I know that the problem is from my PC, cause from others the website works just fine.

What I have tried

1) Close all the browsers,

Run cmd as admin and type `ipconfig /flushdns`, which actually outputs the success message

```
Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

Clear the browsers' entire cache and then restarting the computer

2) Resetting the WiFI modem

I use Windows 7

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your hosts file if there are any entries that shouldn't be there.

Location: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (the actual file is called hosts)

Use `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by `ipconfig /registerdns`

EDIT: Problem solved by itself. It just takes some time for the DNS changes to propagate to every ISP.

Comment: What happens if you ping the website? Is it the wrong or the right server you get a reply from? Do you happen to have a web server on your machine that has domain name binding configuration? What are the results from other computers on your network?

Comment: when I ping it, it shows the ips of the first(old/wrong) DNS,  I have xampp installed on my PC, but I have checked everything. I have virtual hosts created, but associated with my domain - nothing. I have  wifi router, First computer is connected through LAN, and I am connected by WIFI, from both PCs it does not work. I tried to connect without WIFI router - at once to Internet modem(and restarted it as well) - still no result. THanks

Comment: If you have changed the DNS settings at your registrar it can take some time for the changes to propagate to every ISP. Up to 48 hours actually. The fact that both computers on your network has the same problem means that there probably is nothing wrong with your computers. What happens if you change your DNS server (either on the computer or your router) to Google DNS or OpenDNS? Google uses `8.8.8.8`. Can you reach the correct website then?

Comment: Man thanks for your time, I just found out that it started working, I did not do anything, so perhaps it was just matter of time as u just said. THanks :) I think we should add your last comments idea to your answer and mark it as best ?